# ExecuteScalar retuns NULL value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Stored procedure:

```
dbo.GetLDate
select DateEntered from Table1 where Id = 4, Gid=5
```

Result:

```
Executed Successfully
```

New query to verify:

```
DECLARE @LDate datetime
EXEC @LDate =  GetLDate 4,5
```

Results:

```
DateEntered
2014-02-13 06:21:43.600
```

Thus, working fine

Final stored procedure created:

```
EXEC @LDate =  GetLDate 4,5
Select 1
```

in C#

```
int? id = _database.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
```

Here, every time I get null value only. But I am selecting 1 still I get null value. What could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 5):

You are selecting string `'1'` and that can't be converted to `int?` with a `cast`. Hence you are getting null.

Use:

```
SELECT 1 --without single quotes
```

Or you can use `Convert.ToInt32` like:

```
int? id = Convert.ToInt32(_database.ExecuteScalar());
```

Consider the following example:

```
object obj = "1";
int? id = obj as int?;
```

You will get back `null` as cast from `"1"` (string) to `int/int?` will fail.

Comment: Would your `Convert.ToInt32` example really work?  `int?` is a `Nullable<int>`, but `ToInt32` returns an `int`...

Comment: @DanField, yes because there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `Nullable<int>`

Comment: But won't it end up setting a database `NULL` to `0`?  You'd need to check if `ExecuteScalar` returned NULL or not if you actually wanted to preserve nulls, otherwise shouldn't ID just be a regular int?

Comment: @DanField, off course with `DBNull.Value` , `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception. For that you one has to explicitly check. `Convert.ToInt32` code is there to explain the OP what is actually coming back from the proc.

Comment: @Habib Yes, that worked but still I get same error if I change my proc little bit. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: @hellotemp11, what is the change you are doing to your proc ? If that question is related to your current question then ask it here in comments, otherwise open a new question.

Comment: I removed the quote and executed a store proc inside a store proc returning datetime, but still I get NULL result.

Comment: @hellotemp11, there could be issue with your insider proc, try removing it and see if you get the right result back, if it does, then troubleshoot your inner proc. Also see if you can get the error code/error message from SQL server end